# Menu not visible in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have http://tourscript.com/tapas/. The menu is visible in all browsers but Internet Explorer 9. Why? I tried all combinations of z-index. No chance to make the menu appear in Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check with developer tools from Internet Explorer 9 beta, I saw some [Cufon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Inman_Flash_Replacement) tags on the menu part, and I found some FAQ related to Internet Explorer 9 issues for Cufon here,

https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/faq#last-edit

It looks like to solve that, update to Cufon 1.09i,or you could add meta tags to bahave Internet Explorer 9 like Internet Explorer 8 or Internet Explorer 7.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

PS: the Cufon site also says that 1.09i is an updated version for Internet Explorer 9.

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

> UPDATE Oct 24: We have released version 1.09i, which is the same as 1.09 but Internet Explorer 9-compatible. 1.10 is on its way as well. Keep in mind that you do not need to convert your font files again, just replace your old cufon-yui.js with a new one and you're good to go.